# Can I use an integrated modem with wireless router just as a modem with a cable service?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, modem

I live in Seattle, and my mom lives in San Francisco.  She recently called me stressed out about how "the box with lights" doesn't work anymore.  After calming her down, I found that she recently changed from ATT DSL to Comcast cable, and nothing works anymore.

Turns out Comcast set her up with an integrated modem with wireless router.

Could I use her super modem/router/wifi-access-point as a down an dirty modem only, and use a 3rd party wifi router?  Are there any downfalls for doing so?  Maybe I don't need to use their modem at all, but my gut feel is it might make life easier.

I got guilted into coming down next week to get her set up, and want to make sure I have the right hardware when I get there.

Comment: you can't use a DSL modem for a cable service

Answer (score 0):

Could I use her super modem/router/wifi-access-point as a down an dirty modem only, and use a 3rd party wifi router?

Yes you definitely can, if you connect another wifi router into it using a network cable and turn off the Comcast device wifi service via the website interface.

Are there any downfalls for doing so? 
Probably only the additional cost of buying another wifi router when you already have one, but technically no, in fact you can get a much better wifi router i.e. faster and wider range.

Maybe I don't need to use their modem at all, but my gut feel is it might make life easier.
Probably should call their tech support and ask. Often these Internet Providers won't support devices that they don't give you. Or they support limited list of devices and some good one's will help you regardless.

But what I would do before jumping on a plane is just calling the Comcast tech support - more than likely they can fix the issue for you. It could end up being something really simple, like 'activating' a service with a phone call. Good luck :)